# Phantomjs - Silent Browser

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I was using Phantomjs driver for execution of my Application test scenario.

In the Recent update, they have implemented individual certificates to each machines, so once I enter my application URL and hit enter_key, the URL is redirected to an internal server and I need to provide the Userid and Password to Log in.

This Scenario works well in chromedriver but when i'm using phantomjs, the elements are not getting recognized.

I tried to take the screenshots but only blank image came in the screenshot.

Comment: And the question is? ....

Comment: How can i recognize those elements in the redirected URL page?

Comment: What elements? Show your code, please.